# ORACLE APEX PL SQL Procedure Error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex, procedure

I keep getting a the error: success with compilation error. What am I doing wrong with my code? I tried it in sqlfiddle but I get an invalid SQL statement error. As far as I know, this is the correct syntax for PL/SQL

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PRC_CALC
    (W_ORDERID_IN IN NUMBER)
    AS
    W_PARTSERVICEID VARCHAR2(10);
    W_EXIST_FLAG NUMBER(1) :=0;
    W_SUBTOTAL NUMBER(9) :=0;
    W_TAX NUMBER(9) :=0.07;
    W_DISCOUNT NUMBER(9) :=0;
    W_TOTAL NUMBER(9) :=0;

    BEGIN

        SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO W_EXIST_FLAG
        FROM tblJobOrders
        WHERE fldOrderId = W_ORDERID_IN;

        IF W_EXIST_FLAG = 1 THEN

            CURSOR CUR_ORDERCHARGES IS
            SELECT fldPartServiceId
            FROM tblOrderCharges
            WHERE fldOrderId = W_ORDERID_IN;

            OPEN CUR_ORDERCHARGES;
            LOOP
                FETCH CUR_ORDERCHARGES
                INTO W_PARTSERVICEID
                EXIT WHEN CUR_ORDERCHARGES%NOTFOUND;

                SELECT fldPartServiceAmount, fldDiscountPercent
                INTO W_SUBTOTAL, W_DISCOUNT
                FROM tblPartsServices
                WHERE fldPartServiceId = W_PARTSERVICEID;

                W_DISCOUNT := (W_SUBTOTAL*(W_DISCOUNT*.01));
                W_TAX := (W_TOTAL*W_TAX);

                W_TOTAL := W_SUBTOTAL - W_DISCOUNT;
                W_TOTAL := W_TOTAL + W_TAX;

                htp.prn('Your subtotal is: $' ||W_SUBTOTAL||'<br>');
                htp.prn('Your Discount is: $' ||W_DISCOUNT||'<br>');
                htp.prn('Your Tax is: $' ||W_TAX||'<br>');
                htp.prn('Your Total is: $' ||W_TOTAL||'<br>');

            END LOOP;
            CLOSE CUR_ORDERCHARGES;

        ELSE
            htp.prn('The Order Id: '||W_ORDERID_IN||' does not exist in the database');

        END IF;

    END;
```

Comment: You can use `SHOW ERR` after compiling your procedure in SQLPlus in order to get more information about the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable declarations need work

W_PARTSERVICEID VARCHAR2;  should have a size such as W_PARTSERVICEID VARCHAR2(250);

Your number declarations will work but are better to specify a size as well

W_EXIST_FLAG NUMBER;  should be W_EXIST_FLAG NUMBER(9);

W_EXIST_ORDER_FLAG is not declared and should be as well.

As a programming practice that goes beyond your question you should check that the values coming into the procedure and in the cursor are not null or zero.

The CURSOR CUR_ORDERCHARGES should be declared with the other declarations or put inside a new DECLARE BEGIN END block

and you are missing a semi colon when [you FETCH the cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems011.htm), it should be

```
FETCH CUR_ORDERCHARGES
        INTO W_PARTSERVICEID;
 EXIT WHEN CUR_ORDERCHARGES%NOTFOUND;
```

Comment: With the changes you specified, I am still getting the same error  ```ORA-24344: success with compilation error ```

Answer (score 0):

The W_EXIST_ORDER_FLAG used in the first query is undefined. Perhaps, you meant W_EXIST_FLAG?